# call fortran subroutine independently, without definition of that in the arguments

Tags: fortran

I have a Fortran script as below:

```
subroutine source1
    ...
end
subroutine main1 (without argument source1)
    external source1
    call output1(source1,...)
end
```

So I want to know how can make it as Fortran code , means I want Fortran code.

I find something in https://annefou.github.io/Fortran/modules/modules.html   as `Interface definition` that may help.

so what should I do.  Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: Do you mean that you have some script (written in bash, python, etc.) that you want to implement as a Fortran subroutine?  Is there another problem of how to call it?  It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I have some codes in Fortran with compile errors. So I extract what my codes should be as a script (show above), to someone else could reproduce and analyze that and show me as script ,codes or hints that how could modify or implement or regenerate correct codes in Fortran. This is a unique problem I couldn't find the comprehensive solution for that. Is this clear?

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand.  "I have some codes..."  Did you write it?  If not, should it do what you want?  The Fortran code in your question looks like a generic example, not something useful.  Also, if there are compilation errors, you should show them in the question verbatim.

Comment: OK. I use open-source codes. No it stops with errors. So I find the errors and suggest a solution as above script. But I don't know logically how implement them. Also above script is not a FORTRAN code . It's an algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved as replace Fortran corresponded below script in another file , link and compile files together.

```
subroutine main1 (without argument source1)
    external source1
    call output1(source1,...)
end
```